# iOS, how to play multi- videos on the same view?

Tags: ios

I want to play four videos on the same view within a small rectangular area, is that possible ?

Comment: What is the need to play 4 videos at the same time!?

Comment: um... it looks very cool, isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with AVPlayer and using AVMutableComposition.
With AVMutableComposition you can combine multiple sources into one combined playback source - I'm currently working on an Application where i use this to combine different audio and video sources and play it back as a single track even though they come from seperate files.